# Java applet: Where to call repaint();?

Tags: java, sockets, applet, paint, repaint

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I am attempting to write some code to connect to a Lantronix UDS-10 Serial/Network interface. My applet runs, but it won't repaint. If you could give me any pointers, I'd appreciate it. Believe it or not, I actually went to school for this (Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science). However, that was two years ago, and I pretty much haven't touched it since. I'm pretty good when it comes to the basics (classes, methods, variables, etc.), but I'm afraid I'm a bit lacking on the graphics and threading / multi-threading. A lot of the code came from the Lantronix manual (available here: http://www.endurance-rc.com/media/Creating_Custom_Web_Pages.pdf).

The code requires a string of 5 'chunks' of characters, each separated by a space, sent by a ServerSocket over port 10001.

EDIT: The server updates the string regularly. If a window is moved over my applet, the part of the applet underneath the window will repaint. However, I can't seem to find the way to trigger it whenever the characters change.
/EDIT

Any direction you can give me would be much appreciated.

VerifyGas.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class VerifyGas extends JApplet {

static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
tcpip gtp = null;
InetAddress reader_ip = null;
int port = 10001;
TankData tankData;
Text_io text_io;

public void init() {
    gtp = null;
    reader_ip = null;
    port = 10001;
}

public void start() {

    /*  Get the IP address from the HTTP server
    */

    try{
        reader_ip = InetAddress.getByName(getCodeBase().getHost());
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e){

    }

    /* Open a socket to the Device Server's serial port
    */

    if (reader_ip != null) {
        if (gtp == null) {
            gtp = new tcpip(reader_ip, port);
            if (gtp.s == null) {
                System.out.println("Connection failed!");
                gtp = null;
            }
        }
    }
    if (gtp == null) {
        System.out.println("Not connected.");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Connected!");

    /* You may now perform IO with the Device Server via
    * gtp.send(byte[] data_out);
    * byte[] data_in = gtp.receive();
    * functions.
    * In our example we'll use two TextBoxes which have
    * been extended to handle IO to the Device Server.
    * Data typed in the upper text box will be sent to
    * the Device Server, and data received will be
    * displayed in the lower text box.
    */

    /********************************************************/
    /* Start of custom application code */
    /* ADD YOUR CODE HERE */
    /********************************************************/

    text_io = new Text_io(gtp);
    while (text_io == null) {
        System.out.println("text_io is null!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    tankData = text_io.tankData;

    /********************************************************/
    /* End of custom application code */
    /********************************************************/
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    System.out.println("Start paint()");

    this.setSize(200,600);                              // Set applet size

    setBackground(Color.green);                         // Background color

    g.setColor(Color.black);                            // Border color
    g.drawRect (0, 0, 198, 598);                        // Border
    g.drawRect (1, 1, 198, 598);                        // Border

    g.setColor(Color.black);                            // Header color
    g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD,20));     // Header font

    g.drawString("Joe's Eatery",   40, 40);             // Location
    g.drawString("126 Main St.",   40, 60);             // Location
    g.drawString("Cape Coral, FL", 40, 80);             // Location

    g.fillRect(2,100,196,2);                            //  Line 1
    g.fillRect(2,200,196,2);                            //  Line 2
    g.fillRect(2,300,196,2);                            //  Line 3
    g.fillRect(2,400,196,2);                            //  Line 4
    g.fillRect(2,500,196,2);                            //  Line 5

    g.drawString("Tank Pressure",      30,130);         // Header text
    g.drawString("Discharge Pressure",  9,230);         // Header text
    g.drawString("Tank Weight",        35,330);         // Header text
    g.drawString("Temperature (F" +
            (char) 176 + ")",          25,430);         // Header text
    g.drawString("Nitrogen Pressure",  18,530);         // Header text

    g.setColor(Color.red);                              // Color of digits
    g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD,48));     // Style of digits


    while(tankData == null) {
        System.out.println("tankData is null!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    g.drawString(tankData.getTankPressure(),  55, 180); // Digits
    g.drawString(tankData.getDischPressure(), 55, 280); // Digits
    g.drawString(tankData.getWeight(),        55, 380); // Digits
    g.drawString(tankData.getTemperature(),   70, 480); // Digits
    g.drawString(tankData.getNitPressure(),   55, 580); // Digits

    System.out.println("End paint()");

} // End of paint()

public void destroy() {
    if (gtp != null)
    gtp.disconnect();
    gtp = null;
}
public void stop() {

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame("VerifyGas");
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    VerifyGas ap = new VerifyGas();
    frame.add(ap);
    ap.init();
    ap.start();
    frame.pack();
}
}
```

Text_io.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Text_io extends JPanel implements Runnable {

static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
private tcpip gtp;
Thread timer;
TankData tankData;

public Text_io(tcpip tp) {
    gtp = tp;

    // GUI WAS HERE

    tankData = new TankData();
    timer = new Thread(this);
    timer.start();
}

public void run() {
    this.validate();
    int i;
    byte[] in;
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
    while (timer == me) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        if ( (gtp != null) && ((i = gtp.available()) > 0) ) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            in = gtp.receive();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            /* remove non-printing bytes */
            for (i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
                if (in[i] < 0x20)
                    in[i] = 0x20;
            }
            if(in.length >= 5) {
                tankData.loadTankData(in);
                System.out.println("Text_io.TankData loaded!");
                tankData.printValues();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

tcpip.java

```
import java.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/*
* This class opens a TCP connection,
* and allows reading and writing of byte arrays.
*/

public class tcpip {

protected Socket s = null;
public DataInputStream dis = null;
protected DataOutputStream dos = null;

public tcpip(InetAddress ipa, int port) {

    Socket s1 = null;

    try { // Open the socket
        s1 = new Socket(ipa.getHostAddress(), port);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening socket");
        return;
    }

    s = s1;

    try { // Create an input stream
        dis = new DataInputStream(new
            BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error creating input stream");
    }
    try { // Create an output stream
        dos = new DataOutputStream(new
                BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error creating output stream");
    }
}
public synchronized void disconnect() {
    if (s != null) {
        try {
            s.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){

        }
    }
}

public synchronized void send(byte[] temp) {
    try {
        dos.write(temp, 0, temp.length);
        dos.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error sending data : " + ex.toString());
    }
}

public synchronized void send(byte[] temp, int len) {
    try {
        dos.write(temp, 0, len);
        dos.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error sending data : " + ex.toString());
    }
}

public synchronized void send(String given) {
    // WARNING: this routine may not properly convert Strings to bytes
    int length = given.length();
    byte[] retvalue = new byte[length];
    char[] c = new char[length];
    given.getChars(0, length, c, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        retvalue[i] = (byte)c[i];
    }
    send(retvalue);
}

public synchronized byte[] receive() {

    byte[] retval = new byte[0];
    try {
        while(dis.available() == 0); /* Wait for data */
    }
    catch (IOException e){

    }
    try {
        retval = new byte[dis.available()];
    }
    catch (IOException e){

    }
    try {
        dis.read(retval);
    }
    catch (IOException e){

    }
    return(retval);
}

public int available() {
    int avail;
    avail = 0;
    try {
        avail = dis.available();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return(avail);
}
}
```

TankData.java

```
public class TankData {

private String Weight;
private String TankPressure;
private String DischPressure;
private String NitPressure;
private String Temperature;

public TankData() {

    this.Weight = "";
    this.TankPressure = "";
    this.DischPressure = "";
    this.NitPressure = "";
    this.Temperature = "";

}

public void loadTankData(byte[] data) {

    String in = new String(data);

    String[] TankDataString = in.split(" ");

    this.Weight = TankDataString[0];
    this.TankPressure = TankDataString[1];
    this.DischPressure = TankDataString[2];
    this.NitPressure = TankDataString[3];
    this.Temperature = TankDataString[4];

}

public void printValues() {
    System.out.println ("Weight: " + Weight);
    System.out.println ("Tank Pressure: " + TankPressure);
    System.out.println ("Discharge Pressure: " + DischPressure);
    System.out.println ("Nitrogen Pressure: " + NitPressure);
    System.out.println ("Temperature: " + Temperature);
}

public String getWeight() {
    return Weight;
}

public String getTankPressure() {
    return TankPressure;
}

public String getDischPressure() {
    return DischPressure;
}

public String getNitPressure() {
    return NitPressure;
}

public String getTemperature() {
    return Temperature;
}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - you should really start by doing simpler tasks.  An applet getting it's information from a socket is not a 'simple' task.

Comment: Have you tried calling repaint() after you call tankData.printValues()?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: accessing any component properties _must_ happen on the EDT (which you _must not_ sleep on :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everybody. I ended up looking very closely at the sample code provided by the company, and ended up a major overhaul of my code, just short of a complete re-write. My friend and co-worker on this project had started re-working the code, and I took it that he knew what he was doing. Then I realized he didn't have a clue. He had just bought Java books and sat down and started typing away. After I realized the line "add(new Text_io(gtp));" was adding a class that extended JPanel, everything fell into place.
Kleopatra, what do mean by Java naming conventions? Example pls?